# Configure SMTP in IIS using vbscript

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, smtp, iis-6

Really need your help or idea how to create a path in drop directory and disable "enable drop directory quota".In SMTP virtual server properties, how do i uncheck all the options in Messages tab and change the path in Badmail directory .

and also how do I run New SMTP Domain Wizard in alias and create domain name.

Really appreciate all your help.. thanks

Comment: You do know that all IIS are different as well as correlated smtp servers? And latest IIS 7.5 does not come with SMTP at all... So, it would be nice if question would be more specific of what and where you trying to do.

Comment: Hi All Blond, i would like to configure SMTP in IIS6,path c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if my question is not nclear. I'm very new to this vbscript, but i managed to find the solution..this fix my problems

```
set objItemSMTPServer=GetObject("IIS://localhost/SMTPSVC/1")
objItem.DropDirectory = "D:\data\IIS\mailroot\Badmail" <-- Directory path
objItemSMTPServer.RouteAction = 8388609 <-- Uncheck "Enable drop directory quota


objItem.BadMailDirectory = "D:\data\IIS\mailroot\Badmail"
objIte.MaxMessageSize = 0
objItem.MaxSessionSize = 0
objItem.MaxBatchedMessages = 0
objItem.MaxRecipients = 0
objItem.setinfo

Set domainObject = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/SMTPSVC/1/domain") <-- Create new SMTP
Set newDomain = domainObject.Create ("IIsSmtpDomain","alias")
newDomain.RouteAction = 16
newDomain.RouteActionString = "alias"
newDomain.SetInfo
```

This works well form me